# Disable radio button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some forms with some radio buttons elements. I want to disable just one of the radios buttons (those named 'option 1') once a button is selected. This is the HTML:

```
<h2>Option 1</h2>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option 1" value="A" />Value A
  <input type="radio" name="option 1" value="B" />Value B
</form>

<h2>Option 2</h2>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option 2" value="C" />Value C
  <input type="radio" name="option 2" value="D" />Value D
</form>
```

And I'm using this code:

```
$(":radio").click(function() {
  var radioName = "option 1"; 
  $(":radio[name='" + radioName + "']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true); 
});
```

It works... but if a radio button 'option 2' is selected first then the 'option 1' radio buttons are disabled (they should remain enabled until clicked). How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attaching the event to all radio buttons, but you should attach the event just to the ones that will disable themselves. Check my snippet.

```js
$('input[type="radio"][name="option 1"]').click(function() {
  var radioName = "option 1"; 
  $('input[name="' + radioName + '"]:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", true); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Option 1</h2>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option 1" value="A" />Value A
  <input type="radio" name="option 1" value="B" />Value B
</form>

<h2>Option 2</h2>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option 2" value="C" />Value C
  <input type="radio" name="option 2" value="D" />Value D
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery function you select all the radio buttons but what you want is to target only the radio button named `option 1` so update you code like this:

```
$(":radio[name='option 1']").click(function() {
  var radioName = "option 1"; 
  $(":radio[name='" + radioName + "']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true); 
});
```